# Static files don't show up in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, static, jekyll

I'm trying to print my static images in my page following this basic steps in Jekyll documentation:

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/static-files/

My files are in `assets/img` and my config file has these lines (space indented)

```
  defaults:
  - scope:
      path: "assets/img"
    values:
      image: true
```

I have a Jekyll brand new website. Now in my `about.md` page I want to print all the images:

```
{% assign image_files = site.static_files | where: "image", true %}

{% for myimage in image_files %}
  {{ myimage.path }}
{% endfor %}
```

Needless to say it prints nothing.

While I can print `{{ site.static_files | inspect }}` including all files: fonts, images, zips etc I cannot print `image_files` variable, nor `myimage`

What is happening?

Comment: Where did you put the assets folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In root project create folders `assets` and `img` inside `assets` folder.
Put your image inside `img`

**Example**:

```
myblog
.
├── 404.html
├── about.md
├── assets
│   └── img
│       └── filename.png
```

In **_config.yml**:

```
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: "assets/img"
    values:
      image: true
```

In your posts, ex:`about.md`, put something like that:

```
{% assign image_files = site.static_files | where: "image", true %}
{% for myimage in image_files %}
  ![{{myimage.name}}]({{ myimage.path }})
{% endfor %}
```